# Open subsite/library OD4B in phone

Tags: onedrive, file-transfer

My company has OD4B enable for us. I have several libraries and subsites that I can use from my desktop or web.

However when using the OneDrive app in my WP I'm only able to access the Documents library. Is it possible to access other libraries or sharepoint folders? I think if I add office 365 to the Office app I can open the files, but I want to use it to upload, download and manage my folders.

TA